# tkinter auto switch focus after write in entry

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, focus, tkinter-entry

I have got 4 entry fields and I want to switch focus to next field after write one letter. So basically i want to write 4 letters, each one in another field, without touching mouse or Tab button.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
r1= StringVar()
r2= StringVar()
r3= StringVar()
r4= StringVar()

e1=Entry(root, textvariable=r1)
e1.pack()

e2=Entry(root, textvariable=r2)
e2.pack()

e3=Entry(root, textvariable=r3)
e3.pack()

e4=Entry(root, textvariable=r4)
e4.pack()

list=[e1,e2,e3,e4]
for i, element in enumerate(list):
    lista=[r1,r2,r3,r4]
    element.focus()
    while lista[i].get() == "":
        pass

root.mainloop()
```

How can I do that?
Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code hangs before reaching `root.mainloop()` because the Entry() fields will never be edited. You have to use Tk events, e.g. after packing the Entry fields, you could try this:

```
liste=[e1,e2,e3,e4]
e1.focus()
curre=0
def nexte(e):
    global curre
    curre+=1
    if (curre<4):
        liste[curre].focus()
    else:
        root.unbind("<Key>")
        # we've got input into the last field, now do sth useful here...

root.bind("<Key>",nexte)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
all_typed = False
e1.focus()
boxes = [e1, e2, e3, e4]
focused = 0
while not all_typed:
    if focused > 3:
        all_typed = True
    elif boxes[focused].get() != "":
        focused += 1
        boxes[focused].focus()
```

Not my finest code, but should work. I'm not too familiar with TK so I don't know if this will block the app from running or anything.